# parallel execution on device browser with appium and protractor

Tags: android, protractor, appium

I am trying to run my tests on multiple android device's chrome browser. I am using protractor with appium. I am starting 2 appium servers having different ports ie., `4723` and `4725` and specifying multicapabilities with 2 devices information. I tried with both, emulators and real devices. When I ran my config file, both Appium servers are trying to access one device even though I specified the device UDID's. I am very much new to protractor. can any one help me? Below is my config file

**config.js**

```
exports.config = {

      framework: 'jasmine',
      specs: ['Sample.js','Sample_1.js'],

      multiCapabilities: [{
          seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
          browserName: 'Chrome',
           // 'appium-version': '1.4.16',
            platformName: 'Android',
            platformVersion: '6.0.1',
            deviceName: 'abc',
            UDID:'abc',
            shardTestFiles: true
        }, {
             seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4725/wd/hub',
                browserName: 'Chrome',
               // 'appium-version': '1.0',
                platformName: 'Android',
                platformVersion: '4.4.4',
                deviceName: 'def',
                UDID:'def',
                shardTestFiles: true
        }],  


      onPrepare: function () {

      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem sometime ago.

I fixed with two different `config.js` files:

1. One for mobile device using appium on port 4723 `config-mobile-4723.js`
2. Other for mobile device using appium on port 4725 `config-mobile-4725.js`

You only need to split the `config.js` into two files `config-mobile-4723.js` and `config-mobile-4725.js` and then run the two commands parallel using `protractor config-mobile-4723.js & protractor config-mobile-4725.js`

I am not sure if it is the best solution but it works.

More info https://github.com/aluzardo/protractor-cucumber-tests

Comment: Hi Adolfo, Thanks for your help, it is working. But when we give 2 config files it will execute one after another. But i am looking to execute tests in parallel ie if there are 5 tests in spec file then i need to run 3 tests on one device and 2 tests on one device which leads to less execution time.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue. But I was not using protractor. I used Appium with JUnit and Cucumber. For me, even though I had both the devices connected to my laptop, the scripts were always running on the first device which was showing up on "adb devices" command.

I later figured out that I had to use the different combination of **Appium Port, Bootstrap Port and UDIDs**. Providing different values for all these 3 flags worked for me.

**Since you are using Chrome Driver, you would need to provide different value for ChromeDriver port as well**

The below article uses Java Thread for parallel execution, but the approach can be used with other methods as well - 
http://automationtestinghub.com/appium-parallel-execution/

Comment: Hi Anish, Thanks for your reply. I tried setting chrome driver port using proxy as   'proxy': {
            'proxyType': 'manual',
            'httpProxy': 'hostname.com:5679'
          }.    and 5678 for other instance. But still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: I am using appium 1.4.16.1. Is it support multi capabilities